# Javascript in wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am building wordpress plugin that will render google map with shortcode. below code works as an plain php page. but now in plugin file it is not working.

Javascript in my shortcode is not working. HTML in the shortcode is working but javascript is not? How should javascript be inside shortcode?

```
add_shortcode('bikes_on_map', 'bikes_on_map_func');

function bikes_on_map_func( $atts ) {

ob_start();
?>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
function initialize() {
var locations = [
  ["DESCRIPTION", 45.923407054259506, 6.869511535283576, 3],
  ["DESCRIPTION", 41.914873, 12.506486, 2],
  ["DESCRIPTION", 41.918574, 12.507201, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.923407054259506, 6.869511535283576),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    //icon: "/bike_.png",
    animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
}

function loadScript() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&" + "callback=initialize";
document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
</script>


<?php
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
}
```